# Rails Rendering view from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to render a view after sending params to the controller using ajax. I had to go this route due to the project structure but console returns:

```
Started POST "/rate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-17 19:49:42 -0500
Processing by PageController#yourrate as */*
  Rendered page/yourrate.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
  Rendered Shared_Templates/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered Shared_Templates/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 188ms (Views: 187.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

and my ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"rate",
  type: "post",
  data: "start=" + start + "&finish=" + finish + "&duration=" + duration + "&distance=" + distance,
  success: function(){
    alert("Saved Successfully, distance: " + distance); //just for testing purposes.
  },
  error:function(){
    alert("Error");
  }
});
```

and my controller has attributes with params being assigned to them that i'm passing.

Comment: Are you expecting a json response?  Maybe javascript response?  I would recommend setting the dataType option in your ajax call to either 'json' or 'script'.  That way, your controller will know how to respond properly.  Currently, it looks like it's responding with html which isn't what you want.

Comment: What's the question here? I don't see one.

Comment: @ajporterfield apologies for not being clearer, but I would like the page/yourrate.html.erb rendered. the console says it's rendering it but the page that I press the button on where the ajax is being called does not change. Not sure if i should explain in a different way?

Comment: @Toby1Kenobi the page I do this ajax call on does not change to the page i want rendered which console is saying it is rendering: page/yourrate.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of ajax is to do stuff *without any page refresh* so to use ajax to change the view you would need to pass all the html rendered by the controller back as a response to the ajax call then have javascript replace the contents of the current page with the html it gets back from the ajax response.

Comment: So a better choice would be to just replace the content on the current page with a partial that has the content I want to display to the end user?

Comment: @ayounis90 maybe. It's hard to say since I can't see the bigger picture.